# AngularJS 1.6 duplicate http request with interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, setinterval

I have problem with AngularJS 1.6 when i refresh one element after 10 seconds.

This is my controller.

```
$interval(function(){
    if($scope.logged) {
        $http.post('/api/conversions', {
            opened: $scope.opened,
            total: $scope.total_conversions,
            loadmore: false
        },{cache:true}).then(
            function success(response) {
                $scope.conversions = response.data.content;
                $scope.total_conversions = response.data.total;
                $.each($scope.conversions, function (idx, cv) {
                    if ($.inArray(cv.id, $scope.opened) < 0) {
                        $scope.opened.push(cv.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }
},10000);
```

And this is what i get on ajax call

[Duplicate ajax request in same time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A46u.png)

Please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: You're refreshing the element every 10 seconds, maybe you're looking for `$timeout` instead of `$interval`

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is i added attribute in HTML ng-controller.

Comment: The image you added and the fix you are telling doesn't match. From the image, what i understand is angular by default sends an OPTION request when we send an request. Now this is not duplicate request you are sending.

Comment: I tested the code above and I'm getting one request at a time. First one at 10s, second at 20s etc. We will need additional context unless you can check that as @MuhammedNeswine mentions, the first request is the preflight OPTION request.